# How to copy & move MySQL database

Tags: mysql, backup, database, xampp

I'm very new to servers and databases, my experience spanning only a few installations of XAMPP for easy website testing and exploration. So I have XAMPP installed on my laptop, and I just put it on my netbook. I copied & moved my htdocs folder (soon to be synced with dropbox), and now need to move the database.

I am not looking for an extensive backup solution. What is the simplest way to copy my db setup on one XAMPP stack to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is probably by using phpMyAdmin, which is installed as part of XAMPP.

---

### To export

In a browser, open

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Click on **export**

Select your database(s) from the list

Tick the **save as file** box at the bottom of the page.

Click **Go**

Your database(s) will be exported as an SQL file, which you can use to re-create them on your other machine. Copy this file to your laptop.

---

### To import

In a browser, open

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Click on **import**

Browse to the file you just exported.

Click **Go**

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in function of mysql to do this.

If you have direct access to your mysql server by typing `mysql` into your console you can do some backups.

```
mysqldump -p databasename > filename_to_store_sql.sql
```

Copy the .sql file to the new computer/place and do the following.

```
mysql -p databasename < filename_to_store_sql.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

For export all databases:

```
mysqldump --all --all-databases --complete-insert --add-drop-table --add-locks --allow-keywords --lock-tables --quote-names --user=root --password=1234 > ~/Desktop/mysql_all_db.sql
```

For import:

```
mysql -uroot -p < ~/Desktop/mysql_all_db.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative might be to use the [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably copy your database directory inside your laptop's XAMPP mysql **data** directory, and paste that (or replace) in your netbook's XAMPP mysql **data** directory.

Also make sure to copy the individual data files like "**ibdata1**" inside the data folder. This worked for me when i had to move databases across 2 XAMPP versions in my PC.